# SQL Find next Date for each Customer, SQL For each?

Tags: sql

I have some problems with an SQL statement. I need to find the next `DeliveryDate` for each `Customer` in the following setup.

**Tables**

- `Customer (id)`
- `DeliveryOrder (id, deliveryDate)`
- `DeliveryOrderCustomer (customerId, deliveryOrderId)`

Each `Customer` may have several `DeliveryOrders` on the same `deliveryDate`. I just can't figure out how to only get one `deliveryDate` for each customer. The date should be the next upcoming `DeliveryDate` after today. I feel like I would need some sort of "for each" here but I don't know how to solve it in SQL.

Comment: Any good examples on how to use foreach in SQL?

Comment: **WHAT** database and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by **many** database systems - **SQL** is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often **vendor-specific** - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simpler version

```
select c.id, min(o.date)
from customer c 
    inner join deliveryordercustomer co o on co.customerId = c.id 
    inner join deliveryorder o on co.deliveryOrderId = o.id and o.date>getdate()
group by c.id
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i needed. impressivley simple... simply impressive hehe

Answer (score 1):

This would give the expected results using a subselect. Take into account that *current_date*  may be rdbms specific, it works for Oracle.

```
select c.id, o.date 
from customer c 
    inner join deliveryordercustomer co o on co.customerId = c.id 
    inner join deliveryorder o on co.deliveryOrderId = o.id 
where o.date = 
     (select min(o2.date) 
      from deliveryorder o2 
      where o2.id = co.deliveryOrderId and o2.date > current_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a group by. There's a lot of ways to do this, here's my solution that takes into account multiple orders on same day for customer, and allows you to query different delivery slots, first, second etc. This assumes Sql Server 2005 and above.

```
;with CustomerDeliveries as
(
  Select c.id, do.deliveryDate, Rank() 
               over (Partition BY c.id order by do.deliveryDate) as DeliverySlot
  From   Customer c
         inner join DeliveryOrderCustomer doc on c.id = doc.customerId
         inner join DeliveryOrder do on do.id = doc.deliveryOrderId
  Where  do.deliveryDate>GETDATE()
  Group By c.id, do.deliveryDate
)
Select id, deliveryDate
From   CustomerDeliveries
Where  DeliverySlot = 1
```